# SVG линии на фон?

Tags: css, svg

Доброй день уважаемые. Помогите понять где я допускаю ошибку в моём простом примере:

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background: #ED7D31 url("#backgroundLines") 50% 50% repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
<svg version="1.1" id="backgroundLines" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2 12" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2 12;" xml:space="preserve">
<path class="st0" d="M3,6"/>
<path class="st0" d="M-1,6"/>
<path class="st0" d="M3,11"/>
<path class="st0" d="M-1,11"/>
<line class="st0" x1="0" y1="5" x2="2.5" y2="5"/>
<line class="st0" x1="0" y1="11" x2="2.5" y2="11"/>
</svg>
```

Необходимо сделать, чтобы на весь экран были повторяющиеся фон созданный из горизонтальных линий (по вертикале). Линии сделанны в векторе толщиною в 1px через каждые 5рх. Не могу понять где я допускаю ошибку, и почему оно растягивается на всю область? (сейчас они явно не в 1рх)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно сделать так:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background: #ED7D31 url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg version="1.1" id="backgroundLines" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1px" height="6px" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1 6"><line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="5.5" x2="1" y2="5.5"/></svg>') repeat 0px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант интересно. Правда надо было уже писать .main 
  width:100%; height: 100vh;

Comment: @BlackStar1991 ну это уже как душе пожелается)